# How to find max of amount of opportunity related to account?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a below requirement :
I need to find maximum amount on related opportunities and to display on account.
Ex: suppose I have account A1
and A1 have 5 opportunities with amount
o1=>100
o2=>500
o3=>300
o4=>1000
o5=>50
on my account i should have max_opportunity_amount =1000.

I have written below trigger ,but  I am not sure what to do further

```
trigger maxOppAmountonAcc on Opportunity(after insert){

    map<id,Opportunity> oppMap = new map<id,Opportunity> ();
    set<Id> oppId = new set<Id>();
    for(Opportunity o : Trigger.new)
    {
        oppMap.put(o.accountId,o);
        oppId.add(o.id);
    } 

    List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();

    for(Account a : [Select id ,MaxOppAmount__c,(select id,max(amount)  from opportunities) from Account where id in : oppMap.keyset()])
    {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a rollup summary field, as Keith C mentions, is the way to go in this particular case. Being a good programmer means being able to select (and use) the right tool for the job.

In the case of having two objects with only a lookup relationship between them, then [Andrew Fawcett's Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary Tool](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) would be an appropriate tool.

That said, for the purpose of learning, you can accomplish this with a trigger using an [aggregate query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm).

I believe that Salesforce does not allow the use of aggregate functions (MIN(), MAX(), AVG(), etc...) in a subquery, so to make your trigger work, you'll need to use a different query (but it seems like you were on the right track).

Generally speaking, when you have a statement like this

> I want to find the `<some aggregate function>` of `<field>` of all `<child object>` for `<parent object>`

That translates to a query like this

> [SELECT `<relationship field to parent object>`, MAX(`<field>`) FROM `<child object>` GROUP BY `<relationship field to parent object>`]

To make the query work, we need to query the child object in the relationship.
To make the results what you expect, we need to include an Id, and `GROUP BY` that Id.

I'll leave working out the specific query that you need to use up to you (I hope you can work it out from here).

The other thing to be aware of is that using `GROUP BY` in a query means that instead of getting a `List<SObject>` as a result of your query, you'll be getting a `List<AggregateResult>`.

To get any field from an `AggregateResult`, you need to use `.get(<field name>)` (plain 'ol dot notation like you would use with a specific `SObject` won't work). Further, the result of `.get()` is of type `Object`, so you'll need to explicitly cast the result.

For example, in my org, my `Opportunity` object has a field for Monthly Recurring Revenue, `MRR__c`as a Number (i.e. Decimal) type field. If I have an aggregate query like `[SELECT ... MAX(MRR__c) FROM Opportunity ...]`, I would retrieve that result like this:

```
Decimal maxMRR = (Decimal)aggResult.get('expr0');
```

That `expr0` is the default name given to the result of an aggregate function. From the aggregate query documentation...

> Any aggregated field in a SELECT list that does not have an alias automatically gets an implied alias with a format expri, where i denotes the order of the aggregated fields with no explicit aliases. The value of i starts at 0 and increments for every aggregated field with no explicit alias.

You can give an aggregated field an explicit alias by typing a string after the aggregate function, but before the next comma or keyword

```
// Note that 'maxMRR' immediately follows the aggregate function (with a space)
// The same thing applies if the aggregate function is the last field in the SELECT clause
for(AggregateResult ar :[SELECT ... MAX(MRR__c) maxMRR, AVG(Revenue__c), MAX(NRR__c) maxNRR FROM Opportunity GROUP BY ...]){
    Decimal myMaxMRR = (Decimal)ar.get('maxMRR');
    // You can mix aliased and unaliased aggregate functions (though I'm not
    //   sure why someone would want to do this).
    // Since it's the first non-explicitly aliased aggregate function (determined
    //   from left to right), it's implicit alias is expr0
    Decimal myAvgRevenue = (Decimal)ar.get('expr0');
    Decimal myMaxNRR = (Decimal)ar.get('maxNRR');
}
```

Beyond that, all that's left for you to do is to

- Use the Id you used to `GROUP BY` your records
- Grab the appropriate record from a trigger context variable, or create an appropriate record instance (i.e. `Contact tempContact = new Contact(Id = <grouped Id>, otherField = <value>);`)
- Update some data for the in-memory record instance(s)
- DML to save those changes to the database (if you're not using a `before` trigger)

Answer (score 3):

This is accomplished most simply by adding a [roll-up summary field](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/point_click_business_logic/units/roll_up_summary_fields) meaning you are leaving the platform to get the calculation right after all types of changes (inserts, updates, deletes, undeletes) rather than having to write code and tests for the various changes:

[image: Field definitions]

Comment: I need to write a trigger instead of using roll up summary.

Comment: @salesforcebeginner Why?

Comment: I am learning salesforce coding so I am trying to implement max using trigger instead of roll up summary....Account and opportunity are just examples...suppose if I have look up relationship between 2 objects then any how i need to write trigger.

Comment: @salesforcebeginner Hope you are clear that you should use the platform's capabilities rather than write code wherever possible. Put the two objects in a master-detail relationship and your can use a roll-up summary field: illustrates why a correct data model makes later work easy and a wrong data model makes later work much harder. The mechanism for this where you have to write code is [Aggregate Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm); look at various examples of those.